# PCI Compliant Credit Card Vault

Tags: api

I'm looking for a credit card vault where I would be able to store and retrieve the credit card number on demand using an API. Is this possible, is there a product out there which would facilitate it, or is it a breach of PCI?

I imagine it to be a third party with a REST Api I can call. How they store it internally is a black box. Similar to PayPal vault, but I need to be able to retrieve the credit card number. This will be used within my application to charge customers. Most vaults I've found only allow you to store the credit card, and charge it, but not retrieve it.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! That should be a service running on your local Linux machine which you can access using a REST API via TCP/IP? Or rather a database you can access via SQL? Or are you looking for something different altogether? Please specify. For a guide, you can e.g. see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185). Thanks!

Comment: [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) will act as a PCI-compliant black box for storing users' credit card details, and will allow you to charge to those details, but they'll only send you back a token which acts as a reference to the stored card, rather than the card details themselves. (If you wanted access to the actual card details you'd most probably need to be PCI-compliant yourself.)

Answer (score 1):

Check spreedly.com they  offer that API and they are PCI Compliance.